# Magento 2 - How to pass parameter from menu.xml

Tags: magento2, admin-controller, adminmenu

Is there any way to pass a parameter to controller from `menu.xml` file?

**Actual URL :**

```
http://127.0.0.1/mg231/admin/vendor/module/index/key/2c0a132c4b44051ec129440f763a45327b53b5ed09706c4f8d86b9a56c1d7c60/
```

**Expected URL :**

```
http://127.0.0.1/mg231/admin/vendor/module/index/key/2c0a132c4b44051ec129440f763a45327b53b5ed09706c4f8d86b9a56c1d7c60/customparam/value
```

Comment: What parameter you want to add can you elaborate? in url something like ?id=1

Comment: @PrachiSaxena I want to pass string parameter to controller action which is called from admin menu.

Comment: Can you give example? so i can get better idea

Comment: @RutveeSojitra #PrachiSaxena Please check my updated question.

Comment: if you want static parameter you can write action like below:

action="test/index/index/custom/parameter" it will work @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick way to test custom actions is to copy the controller `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index.php` to a test version, where the params can be programatically added like

```
// app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/IndexTest.php
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
// modify request params here
$params['customparam'] = "value";
$this->getRequest()->setParams($params);
```

Just add another menu.xml entry with the test action `vendor/module/indexTest` in this example.

It's not exactly answering the question, but it works as a decent workaround.